# OnPush Change Detection with @Input FormGroups

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-changedetection, ngrx-store

Imagine the following component hierarchy in an Angular 2 application.

```
app.component
└── node.component
    ├── header.component
    ├── body.component
    └── footer.component
```

The app will render a tree of nodes. There is a single 'root' node held in `ngrx/store` to reflect the state of the tree.

The `app.component` gets a "slice" of the `AppState` held in `ngrx/store`, i.e. an `Observable` on the root node.

```
export class AppComponent {
    rootNode: Observable<Node>;

    constructor(private readonly store: Store<AppState>) {
        this.rootNode = this.store.select(state => state.nodes);
    }
}
```

The `app.component` renders the `rootNode` using `async` pipe and the `node.component` (see hierarchy of components above):

```
<app-node [node]="rootNode | async"></app-node>
```

The `node.component` receives the `Node` as `Input()` and renders it using three components: `header.component`, `body.component`, `footer.component`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-node',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class NodeComponent {
    @Input() node: Node;
    constructor() {}
}
```

Note, the `node.component` view does **NOT** use `async` pipe since it's not rendering an `Observable`, but a normal Node object:

```
<node-header [node]="node"></node-header>
<node-body [node]="node"></node-body>
<node-footer [node]="node"></node-footer>
```

Although these child components only render a subset of the node's data, they receive, as `@Input(),` the entire Node in order make decisions about how it should be rendered.

**Important detail:** All three components create a `FormGroup` allowing the node to be edited. However, they also render a view of the same values that can be edited, i.e.

```
<input formControlName="title">
<p>Title {{ node.title }}</p>
```

Since `header.component`, `body.component` and `footer.component` all do pretty much the same thing, I'll just provide the outline of `header.component`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'node-header',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() node: Node;
    @Input() headerForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.headerForm = this.fb.group({
            title: [this.node.title]
        });
    }
}
```

A `FormBuilder` creates a `FormGroup` and binds to the `title` **property** of the Node received from `@Input()`. The `<node-header>` will render both the form control for editing, and the value:

```
<div [formGroup]="headerForm">
    <input formControlName="title"name="title">
</div>
<p>Title {{ node.title }}</p>
```

Both the `node.component` and `header.component` use `OnPush` Change Detection strategy since the number of nodes can grow very large.

**Question / Problem**
`{{ node.title }}` is not updated when the `input` control is edited. I suspect this is because the value in `ngrx/store` hasn't changed and so the Observable in `app.component` doesn't get notified, and change detection doesn't run.

```
<!-- Not updated when input control edited. -->
<app-node [node]="rootNode | async"></app-node>
```

I can't remember where I read it, but I *thought* change detection wasn't needed if a component updated it's (own) data-bound properties. However, in this example, `header.component` binds to a **property** of node - therefore the view, `{{ node.title }}`, isn't updated. To be clearer, I've added some comments to the `header.component`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'node-header',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() node: Node;
    @Input() headerForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.headerForm = this.fb.group({
            // Binds to property of node.
            // {{node.title}} won't update even thought it's "local".
            title: [this.node.title]
        });
    }
}
```

What can I do here to ensure the view is updated instantly as the user makes edits, and only later, push the changes to `ngrx/store`?

Comment: When you type into the input you're actually changing the value inside the FormControl 'title' from the form group. The binding to node.title is showing the object from state, so I would say it works as expected.

Comment: If you bind the template to the value from the headerForm it should update as you type. Something like {{ headerForm.controls.title.value }}